# Async/Await seems to have different behaviour in class methods and function expressions (React Hooks, Redux-Thunk)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, redux-thunk

I'm migrating a class-based react system to hooks, and I'm facing some challenges which I can't understand.

Take a look at the snippet below:

```
async onSearchforOptions(elementId) {
    await this.props.onFetchOperatingSystems()
    //(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
    console.log(this.props.operatingSystems)
}
```

In this method, I am dispatching an action to update the redux state, and right after this I'm logging the result to make sure the information was fetched and updated in the redux state.

The problem is that in an application which uses functional components, the result doesn't seem the same. Instead of updating the redux state and recovering the info right after, it simply doesn't seem to update the state, even if I'm using "await" and the very same actions and reducers the class component is using:

```
const onSearchforOptions = async (elementId) => {
    await props.onFetchOperatingSystems()
    //[]
    console.log(props.operatingSystems)
}
```

My connection for both components (the class component and the functional component):

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    operatingSystems: state.operatingSystemReducer.operatingSystems
  }
}

const mapDispathToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    onFetchOperatingSystems: () => dispatch(actions.fetchOperatingSystems())
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispathToProps)(productsForm)
```

My actions:

```
export const fetchOperatingSystemsStart = () => {
    return {
        type: actionTypes.FETCH_OPERATING_SYSTEMS_START
    }
}

export const fetchOperatingSystemsFail = (error) => {
    return {
        type: actionTypes.FETCH_OPERATING_SYSTEMS_FAIL,
        error: error
    }
}

export const fetchOperatingSystemsSuccess = (operatingSystems) => {
    return {
        type: actionTypes.FETCH_OPERATING_SYSTEMS_SUCCESS,
        operatingSystems: operatingSystems
    }
}

export const fetchOperatingSystems = () => {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(fetchOperatingSystemsStart())
        return axios.get(url)
            .then(response => {
                const fetchedData = []
                for (let key in response.data) {
                    fetchedData.push({
                        ...response.data[key],
                        id: response.data[key].id
                    })
                }

                dispatch(fetchOperatingSystemsSuccess(fetchedData))
            })
            .catch(error => {
                if (error.response !== undefined) dispatch(fetchOperatingSystemsFail(error.response.data))
                else dispatch(fetchOperatingSystemsFail(error))
            })
    }
}
```

My Reducer:

```
const initialState = {
    operatingSystems: [],
    loading: false
}

const fetchOperatingSystemsStart = (state) => {
    return updateObject(state, { loading: true })
}

const fetchOperatingSystemsSuccess = (state, action) => {
    return updateObject(state, { operatingSystems: action.operatingSystems, loading: false  })
}

const fetchOperatingSystemsFail = (state) => {
    return updateObject(state, { loading: false })
}

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case actionTypes.FETCH_OPERATING_SYSTEMS_START: return fetchOperatingSystemsStart(state)
        case actionTypes.FETCH_OPERATING_SYSTEMS_SUCCESS: return fetchOperatingSystemsSuccess(state, action)
        case actionTypes.FETCH_OPERATING_SYSTEMS_FAIL: return fetchOperatingSystemsFail(state)
        default: return state
    }
}

export default reducer
```

updateObject function:

```
export const updateObject = (oldObject, updatedProperties) => {
const element =  {
    // The values of the object oldObject are being spread, at the same time the values of
    // updatedProperties are (I'm taking out the attributes of both objects with the spread operator).
    // In this case, since the names of the attributes are the same,
    // the attributes (which were spread) of the first object will have their values replaced
    // by the values of the second object's attributes.
    ...oldObject,
    ...updatedProperties
}

return element
```

}

My Goal:

Accoding to the snippet below, my goal is to dynamically search for options and update it in my form, which is in the component state.

```
  const onSearchforOptions = async (elementId) => {
    let elementUpdated
    switch (elementId) {
      case 'operatingSystem': {

        await props.onFetchOperatingSystems()
        console.log(props.operatingSystems)

        elementUpdated = {
          'operatingSystem': updateObject(productsForm['operatingSystem'], {
            selectValue: {
              value: props.selectedElement.operatingSystem ? props.selectedElement.operatingSystem.id : undefined,
              label: props.selectedElement.operatingSystem ? props.selectedElement.operatingSystem.name : undefined
            },
            elementConfig: updateObject(productsForm['operatingSystem'].elementConfig, {
              options: props.operatingSystems
            })
          })
        }
        break
      }
      case 'productType': {
        await props.onFetchProductTypes()
        elementUpdated = {
          'productType': updateObject(productsForm['productType'], {
            selectValue: {
              value: props.selectedElement.productType ? props.selectedElement.productType.id : undefined,
              label: props.selectedElement.productType ? props.selectedElement.productType.name : undefined
            },
            elementConfig: updateObject(productsForm['productType'].elementConfig, {
              options: props.productTypes
            })
          })
        }
        break
      }
      default: break
    }

    const productsFormUpdated = updateObject(productsForm, elementUpdated)

    setProductsForm(productsFormUpdated)
  }
```

Comment: does `updateObject` mutates store variable? to me it looks the only way so you got your data in the same render-cycle(not sure if there is better term) action been called.

Comment: in both cases you should get `this.props.operatingSystems` updated in next `render` run only(regardless of `await` and class-vs-functional-based-components)

Comment: No, it only returns a clone. I've just updated the question with the updateObject code. Take a look at that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `props` object passed to the render function initially is not going to be mutated; rather the props passed to your component on its *next* render will be updated. This is more in keeping with the flux architecture. You fire-and-forget an action, the reducer runs, and then your component is re-rendered with new props.

Before, this same thing was happening, but the new props were being assigned to `this.props` again. Since there's no meaningful "this" anymore, you can't use this pattern. Besides, depending on this behavior is not idiomatically the React way of doing things.

**Update**:

I think this is like a great number of cases I've also encountered where the React team seemed to overcorrect for a lot of use cases of people handling derived state poorly (see [You Probably Don't Need Derived State](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html)). I've seen plenty of cases, like yours, where the now-deprecated `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle method solved this problem for class-based components very nicely.

Thankfully, `useEffect` now gives you something like a replacement. Think about it this way: when `props.operatingSystems` changes, you want to perform the *effect* of changing the state of your form. It's an unfortunate double update issue, but you had that before. Here's how you could go about writing that:

```
const [productsForm, setProductsForm] = useState(...);

useEffect(() => {
  // Handle the case where props.operatingSystems isn't initialized?
  if (!props.operatingSystems || !props.selectedElement.operatingSystem) 
    return;

  setProductsForm({
    ...productsForm,
    operatingSystem: {
      ...productsForm.operatingSystem,
      selectValue: {
        value: props.selectedElement.operatingSystem.id,
        label: props.selectedElement.operatingSystem.name
      },
      elementConfig: {
        ...productsForm.operatingSystem.elementConfig,
        options: props.operatingSystems
      }
    }
  });
}, [props.operatingSystems]);
```

The way this works is that your effect code is only kicked off whenever your `props.operatingSystems` value changes since the last render. You can do a similar sort of effect for product types.

Another option which is maybe less elegant is for your async function that kicked off the redux actions to also resolve to a value which you can then use in your state setting code:

```
const operatingSystems = await props.onFetchOperatingSystems();
// ...now set your state
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jacob. Would you suggest a different way to solve this problem?

I'll edit my question to make my goal easier to understand.

Comment: Yep, happy to do so.

Comment: Just updated the question with what I am doing (or trying to do)! :)

Comment: The key point is: options: props.operatingSystems and options: props.productTypes.

Comment: The `operatingSystems` prop isn't updated in the next render? Looks like you have that as a derived prop...

Comment: But actually, I wanted it to be updated in this same render, so I could update the form right after dispatching the action.

Comment: What is `setProductsForm`? Is that a `useState` setter?

Comment: Exactly. This component has an internal state, which is his own form.

Comment: Jacob, thanks for the smart answer. I confess that before reading your update I'd already corrected this issue exactly the way you told us, but your answer gave me more conviction about this.

Comment: One more simple question related to this: sometimes I feel I need to use more than one useEffect in a component (for example.: in this example I need one to handle this way with the operatingSystems and one to do the same thing with product types). Is this normal?

Comment: @PedroArvellos: yep, was thinking the same thing. Since you only want to trigger the effect for certain props, that seems like the only way.

Answer (score 0):

i usually implements thunks in a functional component like:

```
`export default connect(mapStateToProps, {fetchOperatingSystems})(productsForm)`
```

can you try this and comment back.

Comment: Hello Pramod! Sorry, I didn't understand that, can you explain again? I use the object mapDispatchToProps because I have more than one returning, for example:

`const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    onGetProductById: (id) => dispatch(actions.getProductById(id)),
    onFetchProductTypes: () => dispatch(actions.fetchProductTypes()),
    onFetchOperatingSystems: () => dispatch(actions.fetchOperatingSystems())
  }
}`

Comment: i meant to say just write this way and try if that is working since i used this way many times. if multiple thunks are there then mention in the {fetchOperatingSystems,...moreThunks}. and do let me know if that works